# What is the right syntax of Mysql query

Tags: mysql

Here are two tables-

```
table1 wp_posts-

ID      post_type
1078    soto_user
1079    soto_user
1080    soto_user


table2 usuario

ID     post_type
0       soto_user
0       soto_user
0       soto_user
```

I want table2 as-

```
   ID       post_type
  1078       soto_user
  1079       soto_user
  1080       soto_user
```

I have tried this syntax but no works-

```
UPDATE usuario
LEFT JOIN wp_posts
ON usuario.post_type=wp_posts.post_type
SET usuario.ID = wp_posts.ID
```

What is the right syntax of above query. here ID column in table2 is Neither a primary key nor auto-increment field.

Comment: What all other columns are there in your tables? I tried with your tables; they gave me an error. Please post if you have any other columns in your tables

Comment: Basically, you're stuck. Without a PRIMARY KEY, this problem is technically insoluble - although there are probably some 'hack' workarounds. A better idea would be to redesign t2.

Comment: As said by @Strawberry a majority of the issue could be related to not having a primary key and a good DB design makes less effort on query writing.

Answer (score 0):

Here `post_type` is not unique column to make a join. if you make a join, the each row of `table1` will join to 3 rows of `table2` which results in inflation of rows.

If you are looking for the same table as `table1`, you can use the following approach:

```
create table table2
select * from table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query.
This query shall work **if you are not using safe mode to update** (To update a table without a where that uses a key column)

To disable safe mode toggle the option in preferences --> SQL Editor --> Query Editor and Reconnect

```
UPDATE usuario u
       JOIN wp_posts w
       ON u.post_type=w.post_type
SET u.id = w.id;
```

But this is not recommened.

You can use where clause in your query

```
UPDATE usuario u
       JOIN wp_posts w
       ON u.post_type=w.post_type
SET u.id = w.id;
where u.id = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use cursor for update all records.

```
DECLARE ID INT,
DECLARE POSTTYPE VARCHAR
DECLARE CURSOR crs_wp_posts FOR SELECT ID,POSTTYPE
OPEN crs_wp_posts
FETCH crs_wp_posts INTO ID, POSTTYPE
UPDATE usuario SET usuario.Id = ID WHERE usuario.Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM usuario WHERE usuario.Id = 0)
CLOSE crs_wp_posts
```

Comment: this question is about MySQL

Comment: yeah, i know that and i gave an answer about how to do that in mySql. What is wrong?